# How to do a while loop within a while loop in imacros

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, imacros

I want to do a while loop within a while loop in `imacros` but I'm sort of lost on how to do it.
Basically the while loop will have an value counting up and down. I've also attached a code at the bottom, better explaining what I wanted it to do.

```
VERSION BUILD=1002 RECORDER=CR
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
URL GOTO=LINK_TO_SITE
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35
WAIT SECONDS=2
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35
WAIT SECONDS=2

' Do a while loop within a while loop where COUNT_DOWN is the outer loop (and counts down by 1 from 11), and COUNT_UP is the inner loop (and counts up by 1 from 0). If COUNT_UP is equal to 30, then it does a WAIT for 60 seconds.

TAG POS=COUNT_DOWN TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Open<SP>
TAG POS=COUNT_UP TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Make
WAIT SECONDS=60
```

As explanation below are inherited while-loops in `javascript`, but my question is how to realize that in `imacros`:

```
int i = 11;
while (i > 0) {

    TAG POS=i TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Open<SP>
//          ^ i value
    int j = 1;
    while (j <= 31) {

        TAG POS=j TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Make
//              ^ j value
        if (j == 30) {
            WAIT SECONDS=60
        }

        j++;
    }

    i--;
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Please describe by editing your question.

Comment: @David I don't understand how to code this while loop in imacros

Comment: thanks, I adjusted the question for you to make it a bit more clear.